# Testing fgets returning false

Tags: php, unit-testing, stream, phpunit

I am trying to write a unittest for a function that looks a bit like this:

```
function read($stream) {

  $line = fgets($stream);
  if (feof($stream)) {
     throw EofException('...');
  }
  if ($line === false) {
     throw new ReadException('Stream error!');
  }
  return $line;

}
```

One way to call this function would be:

```
$h = fopen(__FILE__,'r');
$line = read($h);
```

I'm trying to figure out how to simulate `fgets` returning false in a case where we haven't hit the end of the file. I want to write a unittest for the `ReadException` case.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: while(($line = fgets($stream)) !== FALSE) { /*do your stuff*/ } you have to read all lines until your reach the EOF.

Answer (score 2):

I found a very easy way to do this:

```
$h = fopen(__FILE__,'a');
read($h);
```

By supplying a stream that's write only, we can easily get `fgets` to return false and trigger the exception.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you're testing is in a namespace you can use this trick:

```
namespace App {

    //fgets is a "mock" for the one from global namespace
    function fgets($handle, $length = 1024) {
        return false;
    }

    class ReadException extends \Exception {

    }

    function read($stream) {
        //this calls the function in the namespace because it exists
        //otherwise falls back to the global one
        $line = fgets($stream);

        if (feof($stream)) {
            throw EofException('...');
        }

        if ($line === false) {
            throw new ReadException('Stream error!');
        }

        return $line;
    }

}
```

Then your test in global namespace would look like so:

```
class FileTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testReadErrorThrowsReadException() {
        $handler = fopen(__FILE__, 'r');

        $this->setExpectedException('App\ReadException');

        App\read($handler);
    }

}
```

The test above should pass.

Now if you don't have access to namespaces I think you have to rewrite the read function to use a "reader" object. Something like this:

```
function read($stream, FileReader $reader) {
    $line = $reader->fgets($stream);

    if (feof($stream)) {
        throw EofException('...');
    }

    if ($line === false) {
        throw new ReadException('Stream error!');
    }

    return $line;
}

interface FileReader {

    public function fgets($handle, $length = 1024);
}
```

Then the test would be:

```
class FileTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testReadErrorThrowsReadException() {
        $handler = fopen(__FILE__, 'r');

        $readerMock = $this->getMock('FileReader');
        $readerMock->expects($this->once())
                ->method('fgets')
                ->with($handler)
                ->will($this->returnValue(false));

        $this->setExpectedException('ReadException');

        read($handler, $readerMock);
    }

}
```

The second test should pass as well.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate example. I understand that it's always possible to refactor the source and let something else handle it, but that's not really a scalable solution. I don't want to end up overloading every PHP method, I was mostly just wondering if I could make the built-in return false ;). I did end up finding a pretty simple way, so I unfortunately have to accept my own answer. Thanks for being so detailed though!